# Send an acknowledgment to the method call using a Boolean variable (here sent) in Kafka Producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm implementing a sendStringMessage method that returns true if the message is being sent to the topic. But I'm getting error( as indicated in code) Local variable sent defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final.
Or can we create a custom callback function that returns a boolean when the message is sent to the topic.

```
    private KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducerFactory(String message){
        Properties producerConfigs = new Properties();
        producerConfigs.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, Bootstrap_Server);
        producerConfigs.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);  
        producerConfigs.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class); 
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(producerConfigs);
        return producer;
    }
    
    private boolean sendStringMessage (String topic , String message) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = kafkaProducerFactory(message);
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic ,  message);
        boolean sent = false;
        try {
            producer.send(record,  new Callback() {
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        sent = true;    // Error   -->  Local variable sent defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final 
                        logger.info("Kafka Message Successfully received the details by the topic : \n" 
                        + "\tTopic : {}\n"+ "\tPartition : {}\n" + "\tOffset : {}\n" + "\tTimestamp : {}",
                                recordMetadata.topic(), recordMetadata.partition(), recordMetadata.offset(),
                                recordMetadata.timestamp());
                        logger.info("kafka Message send by the producer : "+ message );
                    }
                    else {
                        sent = false;   // Error   -->  Local variable sent defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
                        logger.info("Kafka Message Not received - System Error Message :");
                    }
                }
            }).get();
        }
        finally {
            producer.flush();
            producer.close();   
        }   
        return sent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that `onCompletion` is asynchronous and `producer.send` will likely complete before the `return` line is hit (despite you calling `.get()`), and thus `sent` would not be changed.

One solution would be to not return and relocate the `new Callback` to a method parameter of `sendStringMessage`, and then you don't need a blocking producer call

```
void sendStringMessage(String topic, String message, Callback completionEvent) {
   ...
   producer.send(topic, message, completionEvent);
   ...
}
```